# Smart pointer with allocation on first access

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

TL;DR: is there an implementation of a smart pointer class similar to `std::unique_ptr` that only instantiates the encapsulated object and allocates memory when the pointer is first dereferenced?

**Background:**

We have a `Process` class representing a running process. When a process performs network communication, we record that activity and store it in a `NetworkActivity` class object that is a member of the `Process` class.

`NetworkActivity` is a large class with many member variables. I am trying to reduce memory usage and instantiate `NetworkActivity` objects only for the small subset of processes, that actually communicate over the network.

I could, of course, use a `unique_ptr` in the `Process` class:

```
std::unique_ptr<NetworkActivity> networkActivityPtr;
```

But then I would need to check `networkActivityPtr` for `nullptr` every time I am dereferencing it. If I forget such a check and memory has not been allocated yet, the program crashes.

Is there no variant of `unique_ptr` that constructs the object when the smart pointer is first dereferenced?

Comment: No, there is no standard lazy initializing smart pointer in c++. Maybe you can use a function to perform the check and return the pointer instead.

Comment: You could wrap the checking for null and instantiating in an accessor

Comment: Looks like you have XY problem, Create a method that returns reference to `NetworkActivity` and use it everywhere else. Inside that method check the prointer and initialize if necessary.

Comment: Having a class that lazy initializes like this will create additional overhead, because every access will check for nullptr, and potentially allow bugs to pass undetected (since accessing an empty one of these will create the object which might not be the intended behavior).  It should be fairly easy (if tedious) to track down all the potential first access places and check those to see if you need to create your object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. See this:[Dr. Dobbs article](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708). You would need to write your own wrapper.

However, when your process first starts up, its initialization code creates the instance.

Answer (score 0):

For thread-safety purposes, what you really want is something like `future<NetworkActivity>`. That makes clear the distinction between the act of accessing the pointer value (which is lightweight and trivial to make thread-safe) and *creating* the object (which is heavyweight and requires thread synchronization to make thread-safe). Nobody expects `future::get` to be fast (it can be, if the value already is available, but that's not the expectation), while everyone ought to expect `unique_ptr::get` to be fast.

A type which combines these two things has uncertain performance characteristics. Is `get` something you want to do in performance-critical code? Maybe, maybe not; it depends on whether it's reasonable to assume that the value has already been produced at that point in your code's execution.

You can use `std::async` with `std::launch::deferred` to use a `future` for what you want to do. `std::launch::deferred` ensures that the "asynchronous" process will be executed on the same thread as the caller of `future::get`.